# Tagging multiple git repositories

Tags: git, github

I have 3 git repositories for a project. I want to create a release label.
 is it possible to tag multiple git repos together to specify a particular release?

Comment: Nope. Ideally, you can whatever dependency manager exists for your language. Barring that, tag them all with the same version (exactly, or by major version, or by minor version) and document it.

Comment: Did you get anything on how to achieve this?

Comment: @DarshanaPatel no there seems to be no way if repos are independent. I am just tagging with the same release numbers for each repo manually.

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to achieve this using git submodules.

1. Create a single master repo which should define all your git repos as submodule.
2. Once defined as submodule you can check out the appropriate commit from your individual repos.
3. Once all repos are aligned correctly, you create a commit in the top directory. That will defacto be your cross-repo label.

The master repo can otherwise be empty of files.

More details here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

Comment: This is a clever solution, actually. The different releases of the "master repo" will point to the exact commits in the submodules for that specific release.